# How to get terminating length in length of string in java?

Tags: java, string, string-length

As the strings in C/C++ are terminated with the null character '\0', the strings in Java are terminated with length in length.
How to get this length of string without using any in-built function in Java??

I tried to access it by using charAt() method but its giving out of bound exception. Also charAt() is an in-built method so I want to get it without using any in-built method.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why are you avoiding the `length()` method?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of "built-in method".  A String in Java is a class that has properties and methods.  Is `myString.length()` using a "built-in method" ?  And if so....what is the purpose/value of avoiding "built-in methods" ?

Comment: Your idea of the Java `String` class is wrong. The length is not encoded anywhere in the array that holds the characters. The only way to gain access to the length in Java is with `.length()`.  (There's also a convention for JNI C code.)

Answer (score 3):

I think that trying to find length of a string in Java without using .length() method is like avoiding Java at all. C++ and Java use different approacheds to handle strings.